# Real Analysis Algorithms

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms, book-recommendation

first posting here!

I would like to know if anyone knows a website, blog, book or repository that contains some basic principles of Real Analysis written in an algorithmic way.

I am learning some principles of topology, to then study continuity, limits and derivatives.

Making algorithms for sequences and series helped me a lot to understand the principles involved in these subjects, but it has not been easy to think about algorithms in topology...

This sample book was the closest I found:

https://books.google.com.br/books?id=K0B8BwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=pt-BR&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=cauchy&f=false

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: If “written in an algorithmic way” means solving by following some fixed procedure that you can memorize, then I doubt any real analysis book would suggest that (it goes against the philosophy of understanding the reasoning).

Comment: There are of course repeated patterns in certain kinds of proofs. For  example, all proofs by induction follow the same high-level pattern; proofs by contradiction tend to start in similar ways; proofs that something satisfies a definition start in predictable ways. I think there is a book called “How to solve it” written by a mathematician, which may be of interest.

Comment: Ash's books tend to take an algorithmic approach to proofs and are freely available:  https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/

Comment: I was actually looking for algorithms that can visually show me some concepts. So, instead of spending a lot of time drawing, say,  limit points of a set, some covering or even dense sets on paper, I can see them quickly with several examples on my screen.